# How can I see the IP of a file being currently downloaded?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I have Windows 7 and a download in progress occurring in Chrome.

How can I see the IP of the source server for the file that is currently downloading from?

Comment: Do you have the name of the source server already? Then it could be as simple as issuing `nslookup servername` in a commandprompt.

Comment: `ping servername` will also work

Comment: @TheUser1024 what if you have multiple IPs for that servername?

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: Then you need a more complex approach like the one suggested by barlop. That should tell you the specific IP you are getting the data from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that occurs to me would be to open up wireshark and you'd see a ton of activity for a particular IP address. The pic shows it comes up as non-HTTP traffic but the port would be http(80) or https(443).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hold

```
Ctrl + J
```

You will see the whole link
[image: Servername]
Now try

```
NSLOOKUP <servername>
```

in Command prompt.
[image: NSLOOKUP]